# Is heat conduction impeded at interfaces between dissimilar materials?

Tags: thermodynamics

Sound in air essentially echoes off concrete walls, rather than penetrating them, because of the difference in the material properties of air and concrete.

By analogy, are there pairs of solid materials where their interface would be very inefficient at propagating heat?  Perhaps one material has heavy atoms and soft bonds and the other has light atoms and stiff bonds, and neither has free electrons.

If this phenomenon exists could it be used to create super-insulators, by laminating together large numbers of very thin layers of the two materials?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there can be resistance to heat flow at an interface between two different materials, even if there are no gaps.  It is discussed on Wikipedia, under the heading "Interfacial thermal resistance".  It is associated with mismatches in the frequencies of the thermal vibrations (quantized as phonons) associated with the different materials.

Comment: Interesting. Essentially you're saying that there is an impedance mismatch in much the same way that affects sound and electrical wave transmission. I never knew that!

Comment: I think we all originally learned about heat conduction from the macroscopic perspective: conductivity, heat capacity, thermal diffusivity etc.  But I realized that I knew nothing at all about the real nature of heat flow at a microscopic level, and I wondered whether a frequency-based impedance might occur.  And if it did, could you somehow manufacture a super-insulating material out of numerous very thin layers of two mismatched materials?  Unfortunately for that idea, the effect seems to be very weak, so it might take millions of layers to make an effective insulator.

Answer (score 0):

Sound in air is a percussion wave - way different.  Heat via conduction does not have an interface barrier.  It would just be the sum of the resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Conduction across the interface between two materials mostly depends on how well they are in contact. If you want to make a very good insulator you try and ensure the surfaces aren't in good contact. The ideal is no contact at all - hence the thermos flask.